# Почему ругается Maven? javax.servlet does not exist

Tags: java, maven

При сборке maven ругается на строки:

```java
import javax.servlet.ServletException; //package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet; //package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

И не только на эти.

Почему так? При простом запуске все ок, а при сборке maven что не так? Эти либы добавлены через "Project structure / libs".

**UPD:** pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebBD</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.23</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
                <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
                <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <finalName>embeddedTomcatSample</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                        <programs>
                            <program>
                                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                                <name>webapp</name>
                            </program>
                        </programs>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>assemble</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить библиотеку [javax.servlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html). В данном случае, поскольку `tomcat` встроенный:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    <!--version>8.5.23</version-->
</dependency>
```

---

В большинстве случаев достаточно:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

См. [«Can't import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet»](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7595797/11141611)